# how to expose a service as secure?

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

in a project i want to expose a service to clients for giving a xml file to them. i use web service and soapHeader for authentication. is the way secure? what is foible of it? what is the other Techniques for this aim? i read something about REST. is it for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a WCF service. It will be secure by default.

The default settings create a service using WS-Security. If you have clients that cannot handle WS-Security, you can adjust the security settings downward until your clients can handle it.

Comment: hi john,
wcf is great, but maybe i move the project to other platform! can you give a Suggestion that i can use it in other platform?

Comment: @ali: i have no idea what else you could want from a platform.

Comment: all of my demands there dotNet! but in next, the project run at a HP machine.

Comment: @ali: your question is tagged "C#". Do you want an answer that works on C# _and_ on this "HP machine"?

Comment: absolutely no! :)  i want a technique for use in c# now, and i can use it on other platform (like Java) in future.

Comment: @ali: ok, now I understand. The suggestion would be the same. Use WS-Security if the clients (and your platform) support it.